# My website doesn't load sometimes for users and it says "This website can't be reached"

Tags: mern

I've recently deployed a MERN app using AWS and everything seems to be working. However, I've just found out from some people testing the site that sometimes they can't get onto the site. They just get a "This website can't be reached" message.

Does anyone know why this happening for them, it's never happened for me, but apparently it happens quite a lot for them. Is it something to do with the browser and version they're using?